# What to do when a Question undergoes significant changes after I post answer?

Tags: discussion

Let's say that a question was posted and an answer given.

Other comments and answers persuade the OP to clarify and rephrase their question (which is a good thing), altering the direction and tone of the original question significantly enough that as a result, the first answer posted no longer directly addresses the question being asked.

Should the now-obsolete answer be deleted? Or kept if only to serve archival purposes?

Comment: These might help: http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/43478/332584 , http://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/275071/6366398 , http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/177173/332584 , http://meta.ja.stackoverflow.com/q/1558/15185

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can delete answers, but I recommend to use other ways:

In this case, OP need to accept an answer and repost OP's question.
So if I found a question, I rollback the question, and I comment, "you should accept an answer and repost your question".